# Clarification about an edge-case

Tags: support, stack-overflow, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

[image: Review queue]

After being taunted by the review queue about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196312/how-to-use-tfs-api-to-create-workspace-from-template): This questions might be short, but it contains: A clear question (The title actually contains it), a limited area where the solution should be in (the tfs api). It shows research by telling that `VersionControlServer.CreateWorkspace` doesn't support it and that he is aware he can use tf.exe. A simple google search doesn't yield any answers either.

It might not be the best question, it is however very clear what is being asked, and not the "very poor quality, and needed significant improvements to be useful" the review queue says. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336390/visual-studio-2012-with-tfs-2010-create-workspace-from-template) proofs that there is such a thing as a tfs workspace and a tfs workspace template, and googling learns me there is indeed such a thing as a tfs api. I don't see, if someone would have had sufficient knowledge of the tfs api, why they wouldn't have been able to give an answer, even if that answer was "No, there is no such thing".

**My question:** What is soo incredibly unclear about this question that it needed to be closed with this reason, and why does it serve as an example for other review cases if it's soo incredibly unclear to me why this reason applies to this question. No-one felt the need to inform the user what was wrong with the question. Only 1 out of the 5 people who closed the question has a clue about what tfs even is (he answered questions about this topic). Shouldn't such a review case not be filtered out as an edge case?

Comment: How do you determine that this is an edge case programmatically?

Comment: If I would have to think of something: `if( question contains no comments && question votes >= some very negative number ) { question = edgecase }`. If the question contains comments, I can read the comments to find out what might be wrong. If the amount of votes is very negative (-4 or lower or something), the question is far more likely to be really really bad and I should be able to figure out more easily why the question is bad. I honestly think the question should not have been closed in the first place.

Comment: He wants somebody to write a manual for him.  He knows the proper api function to use but made no effort to document how he uses it, a code snippet is required.  It is also completely unclear how a "template" is supposed to be relevant.  This is not an edge-case, just a plain lazy and poorly documented question.  The odds that an expert will take the time to write the manual are very low.